# Difference between RTM vs SP1 of Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

i have installed Licensed Visual Studio 2008 on my Windows Server 2008 Pc.
(I have already installed VS2005. )

After installation It is showing version '9.0.21022.8 RTM'.
On some machine the same setup is showing version '9.0.30729.1SP’

So what is difference among these two.
1. My problem is that my application is compiling and executing successfully in version     '9.0.30729.1SP’ but not in '9.0.21022.8 RTM'.

1. The problem occurred is for my VC++ application. (earlier it was in c++ now migrated to VC++)
   Description:- I searched and found that dll's under 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC'
   folder is differed in both case and my libraries are compiled in version '9.0.30729.1Sp'.
   So it will give '__forcecrtmanifestRTM' linker error.(I think it is because of mismatching dll versions.)

Please help in this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SP1 is newer.  Install it on your other machine: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en

Comment: thanks.But why the same setup will giving me different version on different machine.

Comment: i installed that but now application is compiled successfully but still i am getting error while execution. error :- 'The application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect.'